# Alternative to cstdlib's rand()

Tags: c++, random

Is there an alternative to rand()?Since rand()(at least for me)is freaking broken.So if you know an alternative to rand() in c++ please tell me.Since every time i run this simple code:

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void Gla()
{
  int L;
  L = rand();
  while(1)
  {
      cout<<L<<endl;
  }
}


int main()
{
    Gla();
    return 0;
}
```

It continously outputs 41, i don't know why it just does.

Comment: Maybe put the assignment for L inside the loop so you get a new random number each pass?

Comment: You may initialize the stdio generator with srand() see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/ You could use something like clock() to initialize the seed. see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/ Also, of course, using c++11 you have access to real c++ random number generator see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/

Comment: Reopened. This isn't a duplicate of the question about `srand`. In fact, it's not about `rand()` at all; it's about the meaning of assignment operations.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: Downvoters: this is a legitimate question, and it reflects a very common beginner's confusion.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with `rand()`. The problem is that the code assigns a value to `L`, then enters the loop, writing the (same) value of `L` multiple times. Keep in mind, once you assign a value to a variable, it holds that value until you change it. So change your function from

```
void Gla()
{
  int L;
  L = rand();
  while(1)
  {
      cout<<L<<endl;
  }
}
```

to

```
void Gla()
{
  int L;
  while(1)
  {
      L = rand();
      cout<<L<<endl;
  }
}
```

That way, the value of `L` gets updated each time through the loop.